# When using deep linking to open an ios/android application from web browser , How can i pass data to the mobile application

Tags: javascript, ios, deep-linking, android-deep-link

Right now I am able to open the applications - both ios and android through deep linking,
But I am redirected to the home screen when the app is opened. How can I pass data to the mobile application so that I can use the data to open a corresponding tab with the data?

[image: sample code]

Comment: Add a path and /or query string to the url that you can use in your app to route to the relevant screen

Comment: Can you give an example of this? How to access the query params and route in ios and android

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Android or react native.  The Apple documentation is here - https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments to a deep link the same way as to a normal URL, though it differs between different apps. With Instagram, you can open the profile of the user `jack` as such

```
instagram://user?username=jack
```

You can find more examples of deep links supported by Instagram [here](https://github.com/Loggy/instagram-deeplink/blob/master/src/utils.ts)